# How is intensity defined for quantized EM fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, second-quantization

Classically intensity is defined as 
$$ I \equiv  \frac{1}{2} c \epsilon_0 E^2, $$
but when you perform a second quantization this definition becomes a bit ambiguous since the $E^2$ could be interpreted as $\vert E^2 \vert $ or as $ \vert E \vert^2$.

So my question is simply: Which is these definitions is correct?

The relevance becomes clear when you consider that $ \vert E \vert^2=0$ for Fock states (including the vacuum state) while $\vert E^2 \vert $ is not.

See e.g. wikipedia for an example of this definition:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity_(physics)

Comment: I suspect that you are thinking of classical waves, in which case the equation you exhibit has the integral already evaluated and it would be much better to use the $\equiv$ on the line in which the integral appears. What you've got is the result under certain assumptions (i.e. a harmonic wave), not the definition. Look at the interpretation of the kernel of that integral and the answer should be very clear.

Comment: Which integral are you referring to? Yes I am considering harmonic waves, but not classically. If you can reference another more basic definition of intensity than e.g Wikipedia then I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think the Intensity becomes an operator which has a form very similar to the electromagnetic Hamiltonian (i.e. with $|E^2|$)

Comment: Rather than answering with a lengthy comment I've written an answer. I should say that I've been assuming that where you write $|E|$ you mean a suitable average rather than a simple absolute value. That notation is not one I commonly encounter; more usually I see $\langle E \rangle$.

Comment: $I \sim \langle\vec{E}.\vec{E}\rangle$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classical you work the intensity of a wave out by integrating the energy arriving over a known area in the course of one cycle, and then divide by the period and the area. The form you exhibit is correct for harmonic waves in SI units if the $E$ is the maximum amplitude of the electric field. But for a general normally-incident plane-wave  you are looking for 
$$\begin{align*}
I &\equiv \frac{1}{T} \int_{t=0}^T u(\mathbf{x},t) \,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{T} \int_{t=0}^T \epsilon_0 \left[ E(\mathbf{x},t) \right]^2 \,\mathrm{d}t \,,
\end{align*}$$ 
where I've written $u$ for the energy density of the electromagnetic fields and $T$ for the period of the wave. I've also taken $\mathbf{x}$ as constant and left out a uninteresting factor of $A/A$. (Of course you can do the integral in space if you prefer.)

To recover the expression you exhibited, just write
$$ E(\mathbf{x},t) = E \sin \left(\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x} - \omega t \right) \,,$$
and evaluate the integral.

Anyway, the kernel of the integral is your guide for how to interpret the $E^2$ in performing the second quantization. You want the average of the square (which is not zero) rather than the square of the average (which is zero).

Comment: To clarify sligthly my vague definition:
Yes I meant the time averaged energy, but I was thinking of e.g. standing waves where this comes out a bit differently.
But your answer is good. Intensity comes from energy density which is <E^2> not <E>^2.
The result is the same except for the contribution from the vacuum. Thanks.